# wpf control background 2-way binding only working one way

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have this button that has a two way binding on the background brush, I've set up a dependency property, I'm also making use of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. But I'm still having problems with two way bindings.

If I update the property that's bound to the button, the buttons background changes, like i would expect however if I update the buttons background directly ("button.Background = Brushes.Blue") the property doesn't get updated.

Here is the xaml for the button:

```
<Button Background="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow,Path=TitleBrush,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The property:

```
public Brush TitleBrush 
{
    get 
    {
        return (Brush)GetValue(TitleBrushProperty);
    }
    set 
    {
        if (!_graph.TitleBrush.Equals(value)) 
        {
            _graph.TitleBrush = value;
            SetValue(TitleBrushProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TitleBrush));
        }
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TitleBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow));
```

The two ways I change the background color:

```
TitleBrush = Brushes.Red; // This works great
button.Background = Brushes.Red; // This changes the background but doesn't update the property
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TwoWay` is for setting values to a bound property and accepting a value back. In your case, you are setting it one way for both cases -- to the control. The control isn't sending a property value back. `TwoWay` is really meant for input fields. If you are using code-behind, you should use the bound property.

As the [`BindingMode` Enumeration documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Causes changes to either the source property or the target property to automatically update the other. This type of binding is appropriate for editable forms or other fully-interactive UI scenarios.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was hoping that wasn't the case. But anyways, I'll figure something else out I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. That's the way WPF was designed to work. If you need to set the control's color programatically, you may want to create a separate ViewModel, put the properties there, set an instance as the DataContext, and work with it that way. Direct access/calls to the controls should be a last resort.